# Get results from Solr facets

Tags: solr, facet, faceted-search

I am pretty  new to Solr, so I don't know if what I'd like to achieve is actually feasible or not.
Currently, I am querying my Solr to retrieve the amount of results that match the conditions in several facet queries. 
For example:

```
localhost:8082/solr/dict/select?q=*:*&rows=0&wt=json&indent=true&facet=true&facet.query=dict1:"#tiger#"&facet.query=dict1:"#lion#"
```

With this kind of query, I am getting the count of Solr docs containing "tiger" and  the count of those cointaining "lion", in field "dict1":

```
 {
  "responseHeader": {
    "status": 0,
    "QTime": 239,
    "params": {
      "facet.query": [
        "dict1:\"#tiger#\"",
        "dict1:\"#lion#\""
      ],
      "q": "*:*",
      "indent": "true",
      "rows": "0",
      "wt": "json",
      "facet": "true"
    }
  },
  "response": {
    "numFound": 37278987,
    "start": 0,
    "docs": [ ]
  },
  "facet_counts": {
    "facet_queries": {
      "dict1:\"#tiger#\"": 6,
      "dict1:\"#lion#\"": 10
    },
    [...]
  }
}
```

The thing is that now I need to get also some results for each facet, aside as the count (for example, three results for "tiger" and three more for "lion")

I have read some similar questions ([Solr Facetting - Showing First 10 results and Other](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1808515/solr-facetting-showing-first-10-results-and-other) or [SOLR - Querying Facets, return N results per Facet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24019531/solr-querying-facets-return-n-results-per-facet) )  , but none of their answers seems to work for me, maybe because I am doing the facets on all docs (`q=*:*`).

Any help will be welcome :)

Comment: I'm not sure how your case differs from the grouping strategy described in the last link you included?

Comment: Because my search is \*:\*, I mean, I am performing the facet to match "tiger" or "lion" over all the entries, and the strategy stated in the last link is asuming that the query is "doing something". For example, if I query with "dict1:tiger", and then add the group filtering as in the second link, it kind of works, but it's not the desired approach...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per mailing list, what about simply using grouping ?

```
solr/hotels/search?q=*%3A*&wt=json&indent=true&group=true&group.query=query1&group.query=query2&group.limit=3 [1]
```

Is this ok for you? This returns 2 groups (1 per query) with the related count and max number of documents.

[1] https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Result+Grouping

Comment: Thank you! I manage to get the results as I wanted: /select?q=*:*&wt=json&indent=true&facet=true&group=true&group.query=dict1:tiger&group.query=dict1:lion&group.limit=2
The only thing is that this query is super slow :/ (From 0,2secs to 2secs)